# Can we assign a class to an element in terms of the opacity value after fade out?

Tags: javascript, html, css, settimeout, opacity

Dears,

I want to create a fade out and resume effect in terms of the opacity of an element, below is my code:

```js
function start() {
  let abc = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  abc.className = "class1"
  const aa = document.querySelector(".class1");
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (aa.style.opacity === "0";) {
      abc.className = "";
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: coral;
  padding: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <p>I am myDIV.</p>
</div>
<p>Click the button to set a class for myDIV:</p>
<button onclick="start()">Try it</button>
```

The code ""abc.className = "class1" is for the fade out, I want the "myDIV" element to resume after fade out.

My thought is after the execution of the code "abc.className = "class1", the opacity of abc will  be zero.  In order to make sure the fade out is complete before it go to the next code,  I apply a setTimeout code so that the code "if(aa.style.opacity ==="0";){abc.className = ""} is executed delayed by 2 seconds.  However, I can't get the expected result, what's wrong in my above codes?  Thanks.

Comment: a tranisition must be in effect to transition ... in other words, if you have an element that has no transition style property, and you apply a style with transition, the transition will NOT take effect - also, the opacity in a class will not be readable in an element.style.opacity ... you need to use `getComputedStyle(aa).style.opacity`

Comment: @Jaromanda  Thanks for your comment,  base on your suggestion, what changes in my above code should be made?  is okay to provide your code answer, i really want to try and see in my computer.  Many thanks!

Comment: i guess what @JaromandaX means is you meed to set the transition at #myDIV.

Comment: @mok_ku In my above code, if you get rid of all others code line and only left "let abc = document.getElementById("myDIV");  abc.className = "class1"", a simple fade out transition can be seen...

Comment: no, what @JaromandaX means is the css transition. you need to move the transition from .class1 to the #myDiv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have a semicolon where it does not belong
- You are selecting something by class, and then change the class so it is not longer found.

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
function start() {
  setInterval(() => myDiv.classList.toggle("class1"),2000)
}
```

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: coral;
  padding: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <p>I am myDIV.</p>
</div>
<p>Click the button to set a class for myDIV:</p>
<button onclick="start()">Try it</button>
```

You cannot ask the style.opacity because it is not available to JavaScript if is was not set on the element directly using style

You CAN test the computedStyle but you need to convert the opacity from `"0"` to `0` if you want to use `===` - I use the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");

function start() {
  myDiv.classList.add("class1")
  setTimeout(() => {
    const compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(myDiv);
    const opacity = compStyles.getPropertyValue('opacity');
    console.log(opacity);
    if (+opacity === 0) myDiv.classList.remove("class1")
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: coral;
  padding: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <p>I am myDIV.</p>
</div>
<p>Click the button to set a class for myDIV:</p>
<button onclick="start()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help at first.  And yes, what you just shown is my ultimate goal.  My original code in this question is to do one cycle at first, and if successful, i will include another setTimeout to do the recursive part.  Yes, I understand your code, but my question is what is wrong in my code?

Comment: My thought is after the execution of the code "abc.className = "class1", the opacity of abc will be zero. In order to make sure the fade out is complete before it go to the next code, I apply a setTimeout code so that the code "if(aa.style.opacity ==="0";){abc.className = ""} is executed delayed by 2 seconds. However, I can't get the expected result....

Comment: I cannot guess your expected result, sorry

Comment: My expected result is what you just've code, but one cycle only, no need over and over.... As i said earlier in my first comment here, what i intend at the beginning is if my original code is successful, then i will add another setTimeout code (i.e. setTimeout(start, 2000) to perform the recursive part.  I want to know why my code  "if(aa.style.opacity ==="0";){abc.className = ""}  don't work...

Comment: Why setTimeout(function() {
    if (aa.style.opacity === "0";) {
      abc.className = "";
    }
  }, 2000); don't work?

Comment: Because the object does not HAVE an opacity available when not set by script

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner, what do you mean by "when not set by script"? and how can i set the object by script then?  Thanks.

Comment: In the very beginning this question,  in the comment section, I was told by  "Jaromanda X" here, she said " a tranisition must be in effect to transition ... in other words, if you have an element that has no transition style property, and you apply a style with transition, the transition will NOT take effect - also, the opacity in a class will not be readable in an element.style.opacity ... you need to use getComputedStyle(aa).style.opacity ", I don't understand what exactly she mean, is relevant?

Comment: Please see the update. You DO need computed style

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly what i want.  I am now still digesting your code.  I had done some study about the opacity before, and somewhere mentioned that opacity = Number(window.getComputedStyle(aa).getPropertyValue("opacity")), but you don't have Number here, or i get that wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) does the same as Number()

Comment: Hi, I have a question about the ComputedStyle, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72991465/19324287 this program is to loop pictures and I have the code opacity = getComputedStyle...there, my question is: "when i tried to only skip that code line, the result is the program only loads one picutre (the first one), and when i include that code line, the program loads all the picture with fading in"  Although this program work, i do want to understand why such phenomenon happen?  If it is possible, your help is much appreciated.  Thanks.